# Why changes in my content do not display on the pages indexed on Google? It's been more than 6 months

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect, content-management-system, permalinks

I bought this website in January of this year for a large amount, ever since I bought this website, the affiliate links, which are the main source of revenue for the site, have not changed, despite trying to change them again and again. Is there any way someone can help so that the right affiliate links appear on the indexed pages of the search engine? The changes appear in the backend, but they haven't changed in the front end for a lot of months, which is very concerning. Please help.

Comment: It depends on your SEO integration & setup.

Comment: (I am bad english speaker, I might not understand something) Maybe the links on the search engine are more viewed, than the link you want to be on here? By the way, what's the link to website? I'm curious.

Comment: -stysan I'm afraid I'd have to reveal the URL of the website, others could copy the niche.